# python read log and write to new file

Tags: python, python-2.7

im using the following code to read file , and write some lines which contain certain word

```
with open('access.log') as f:
    for line in f:
         logdate = datetime.strptime(line.split(',')[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
         if logdate >= datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=10):
             if 'Busy' in line:
                 file = open ('newfile.txt' , 'w')
                 file.write(line)
                 file.close()
```

I still cant get the file created  and data inserted , 
what do i miss here ?

Comment: Did you check the root directory where your `.py` file exists? It should be there.

Answer (score 4):

You keep overwriting using `w` use `a` to append or open outside the loop.

```
with open('access.log') as f, open ('newfile.txt' , 'w') as file:
    for line in f:
         logdate = datetime.strptime(line.split(',')[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
         if logdate >= datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=10) and 'Busy' in line:
                 file.write(line)
```

Comment: @Jecki, no prob, opening once outside the loop is the best option.